# Training a neural net as a classifier when there are no labels

Tags: classification, neural-networks, k-means, unsupervised-learning

I have an ML problem where I have a large data set and in this data set there are N categories.  We have no labels.  I want to be able to take this data set and use it to train a neural network to classify new instances.  To this end, I believe I have to run an unsupervised learning algorithm like K-means and get the categories. This forms a set, Cat which I want to inspect by hand and give all the nice labels for so they are human readable.  Then I want use this set of classified examples as a set of labelled data.  I will then train a neural network to classify according to this set of labelled data.  Does this make sense?  Is there a single algorithm that can do this?

Someone has pointed out that, without labels, only an unsupervised algorithm is useful.  What I am wondering is the following:  After I have ran k-means and classified N samples, can I use this to quickly determine the class that a new sample is in?

Comment: You do not have labels. Hence, such a learning is unsupervised learning. For supervised learning, you need to find the value of N classes. For a large dataset, it may be difficult, but is the only solution if you need supervised learning.

Comment: Are you asking how to use $k$-means to classify new data? Or are you asking whether you can use $k$-means to attribute labels to unlabeled data, and then use these newly-labeled data in a supervised classifier?

Comment: @Sycorax Hi!  Your second point is what I originally wanted, I want to "use these newly-labled data in a supervised classifier".  Is this possible?

Comment: No one's going to call the police on you, but one problem you'll face is that there will inevitably be errors in the labels you generate using $k$-means. $k$-means produces clusters, and somehow a human will have to assign a label to the cluster ("cluster 4 is dogs"), and that cluster will inevitably have some cats, hamsters and peacocks in it. Then you're training a classifier on unreliable data, which will make the classifier that much worse. Garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: @Sycorax  Is this a standard problem with a standard method?  I means is there a standard way of approaching this kind of problem?

Comment: The standard way to solve this problem is to have humans label your data.

Comment: @Sycorax if my unsupervised classifier had a rank so that the borderline cases could be identified, then I can handle that with what I want to do.  Does that exist for any unsupervised learning algorithms?

Comment: An ongoing area of research is transfer learning and one- or few-shot learning. The goal is to allow models to learn from a small number of examples. You'd still have to provide some labels, but the point is to make the required number of labeled data smaller.